# Not getting the clientside message after clicking on Search button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

I am working on `alpha.dubaiexporters.com`. There is a search Panel containing two inputs Keyword and Categories. I wanted to validate Keyword part.

If the user entered less than three characters and clicked on Search button then the clientside message should be displayed saying `the entered input should be more than 3 characters`. I am not getting the clientside message.

The following is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="txtkeyword" name="s" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
<asp:Button ID="Search" class="dt-header-search-submit dt-button dt-button-danger" style="top:0px;width:226px;height:70px;" Text="Search" runat="server" onclick="doit" OnClientClick="return checkLength();" />
```

Below is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkLength() {
            var textbox = document.getElementById("txtkeyword");
            if (textbox.value.length < 3) {
                alert("The entered input should be 3 or more than 3 characters");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void doit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtkeyword.Value))
        {
            try
            {

                String mainsearch1 = null;            
                mainsearch1 = txtkeyword.Value.Trim();
                if (mainsearch1.Length > 2)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("searchmain.aspx?mainsearch=" + mainsearch1 + "&querylevel=1");
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtserach.Value))
        {
            try
            {

                String cat = null;               
                cat = txtserach.Value.Trim();
                if (cat.Length > 2)
                {                 
                    Response.Redirect("searchcat1.aspx?cat=" + cat);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }



        }


    }
}
```

I don't know why its not calling javascript function.

Expected output: I want this alert message when user enter less than three letters in `txtkeyword` textbox.

[image]

Comment: did you tried console logging, if that function and conditional statements are getting called or not?

Comment: where is your  onclick event of doit?

Comment: @ArunPratap...i updated it...

Comment: @TarangRathod...its not getting called as javascript function is not displaying in console

Comment: @chetankambli, I tried your code its working as intended on my side

Comment: @chetankambli, where did u put this script in web form? try to put script inside <body> tag

Comment: @ershoaib....  inside <head>..  it is like this..  <head>.. <script>..</script> <contentplaceholder id="head"></comtentplaceholder> </head>

Comment: @chetankambli, try to put this script inside <body> tag that is just above the closing </body> tag and let me know

Comment: @ershoaib...i put..but it dint worked...

Comment: ok lets try to add your full html to view what the problem it is?

Comment: @chetankambli have you seen your chrome console may be there is some error which is making javascript code to crash?

Comment: If you are using asp.net webforms, consider using its built in validators, much better than ugly alerts.

Comment: @chetankambli have tried putting debugger in the function and consoling the values of the txtkeyword

Comment: @ershoaib..kindly go to this link..   https://jsfiddle.net/17xLdhys/

Comment: I saw your html, the `txtkeyword` and button is on your content page right? if yes then add <script> tag inside your content page and place above script inside this tag

Comment: means you have to move your script from main page to content page that contains your `txtkeyword`, `buttons` and all other

Comment: @ershoaib...no....textkeyword and button is there in a main master page...<header> <content> and then <footer>

Comment: @ershoaib...content is the middle part which is starting from Categories of listing

Comment: @JonP...yes...but if i am doing that the interface is getting changed...i tried Regularexpression validation

Comment: @chetankambli, scripts conflicts occurred here. so try to put your `script` like i put in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/49cf8zwm/, see line 3116 - 3124

Comment: @ershoaib...i placed it but still the same issue....Are you getting the clientside message?

Comment: @chetankambli, yes i got client side message. I update your question with screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine, have a try please :)

```
function checkLength() {
debugger;
var textbox =$get("<%=txtkeyword.ClientID%>"); //document.getElementById("<%=txtkeyword.ClientID%>")
if (textbox.value.length < 3) {
alert("The entered input should be 3 or more than 3 characters");
return false;
}
}
```

Note: you cant access a control directly when runat="server" is there